# Giving transition animations to loading components that come with next.js 13

Tags: next.js, css-transitions, loading

I want to make a transition animation for the loading component that increases the opacity from 0 to 1. The animation works, but when it goes to the next page, it empties the page and a blank page appears in the background during the transition.

Here is a solution I came up with: I put the components on the page into the load component and it kind of copied the background during the migration. but this solution didn't work very well

you can check it here: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/musing-tdd-c56h1h